# T-SQL pivot formatting unexpected identifier when filtering column based on string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

Can someone explain what is wrong with this syntax for creating a pivot in SQL Server Management Studio? I tried adding the identifier ([Name].'email') with no success. [image]

Error message when executed:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'email'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select ID
      ,email as EMail
      ,phone as Phone
From (
....
) aaa
pivot (max([Data]) for [Name] in ([email],[phone]) ) pvt
```

If your system is not case sensitive, you can get away with

```
Select *
From (
....
) aaa
pivot (max([Data]) for [Name] in ([Email],[Phone]) ) pvt
```